# Não consigo verificar se o input type date foi preenchido ou não

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer uma validação de dados, e preciso que o button só seja habilitado quando os input abaixo for preenchidos porém não consigo aplicar isso pro campo input type date

```js
var inputs = $('#NomeColaborador, #MatriculaColaborador, #NomeAvaliado, #MatriculaAvaliador').on('keyup', verificarInputsForm);
let valor = document.getElementById('nasc');

function verificarInputsForm()
{
        const preenchidos = inputs.get().every(({value}) => value)
        $('#botao').prop('disabled', !preenchidos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Informacoes">
    <div class="ColaboradorInfo">
            <label for="NomeColaboradorLabel"
                    id="NomeColaboradorLabel"><strong>Colaborador:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="NomeColaborador" id="NomeColaborador" required>
            <br>
            <label for="MatriculaColaboradorLabel"
                    id="MatriculaColaboradorLabel"><strong>Matricula:</strong></label>
            <input type="number" name="MatriculaColaborador" id="MatriculaColaborador"
                    required>
    </div>
    <div class="GestorInfo">
            <label for="NomeAvaliadorLabel"><strong>Avaliador:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name="NomeAvaliador" id="NomeAvaliador" required>
            <br>
            <label for="MatriculaAvaliadorLabel"><strong>Matricula:</strong></label>
            <input type="number" name="MatriculaAvaliador" id="MatriculaAvaliador" required>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
Data: <input type="date" name="datays" id="datays" required>
<br>
<br>
<button type="button" id="botao" onclick="ContinuarPPrimeira()" disabled="disabled">Continue</button>
```

Comment: Como a pergunta não possui a tag [tag:css] não vou responder, mas veja se esse exemplo o ajuda: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/dis#index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estive analisar o seu código e pode fazer de duas maneiras a verificação do input - onClick (antes de enviar o formulário) e onChange (quando o utilizador seleciona um valor na data). Além disso, nem precisa do atributo required no date, pois não funciona.
Para isso basta usar o seguinte código:

No onClick:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
          <input type="text" name="NomeColaborador" id="NomeColaborador" required>
  Data: <input type="date" name="datays" id="datays" >
   <button type="button" id="botao" 
   onclick="ContinuarPPrimeira()">Continue</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
 function ContinuarPPrimeira(){
  console.log(document.getElementById('datays').value)
  if(document.getElementById('datays').value == ""){
    alert('Não tem data')
  }else{
    alert("Tem data")
  }
}
```

Para a função onChange:

HTML:

```
Data: <input type="date" name="datays" id="datays" required onChange="VerificarDados()">
  
  <button type="button" id="botao" onclick="ContinuarPPrimeira()" >Continue</button>

  
</form>
```

JS:

```
function VerificarDados(){
   if(document.getElementById('datays').value != ""){
    alert('Tem data')
  }else{
    alert("Não tem data")
  }
}
```